# Quota check for ext3 Linux partition

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, quota

I use

```
quotacheck -m /home
```

in cron.daily to check quota everyday. The server OS is CentOS-5.3. I am getting error

```
quotacheck: Quota for users is enabled on mountpoint /home so quotacheck might damage the file.
Please turn quotas off or use -f to force checking.
```

since last few days in logwatch and even on manually running the command. Should I use -f or there is some better way to keep quota files accurate. I felt quota files were not being updated at all until I call quotacheck. Can kernel automatically update quota files when file size changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the manpage of `quotacheck`?

> It is strongly recommended to run quotacheck with quotas turned off for
>    the filesystem. Otherwise, possible damage or loss to data in the quota
>    files  can  result.   It  is  also  unwise  to run quotacheck on a live
>    filesystem as actual usage may change  during  the  scan.
>
> [...]
>
> -f, --force
>
> Forces  checking  and  writing of new quota files on filesystems
>   with quotas enabled. This is  not  recommended  as  the  created
>   quota files may be out of sync.

So do not run it on a live filesystem. At any rate, why are you running it in cron.daily? `quotacheck` is only necessary if the quota data may be out of sync with the filesystem, usually after a fs crash, or if the fs was used without quotas.

During normal usage, the quotas are updated automatically, there's no need to run quotacheck regularly.

Manpage again:

> quotacheck should  be  run  each time the system boots and mounts non-valid filesystems.

So run quotacheck from your boot scripts (should be in there already), and lose the cron job.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought it is not updating so created a cron job for updation. Since quotacheck was not running due to warning since last two three days, I tried to run first repquota -a. Then quotacheck -fm /home. Then again repquota -a. Both repquota -a reported exact same usage. So Kernel is updating quotas without need to call quotacheck regularly. I have removed quotacheck from cron now.

Answer (score 1):

As I know quotacheck should be run regularly from cron (quotachech -ug /home) in order to check aquota.user and aquota.group files.